# How to use 2 panels in applet?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

I am trying to work out how to navigate across multiple panels in swing. I would like to do this by using the CardLayout as opposed to using glass panels as from what I have read it seems that this is the correct tool for this job (however, feel free to correct me if you know otherwise). I have written a test case which almost achieves this but falls short on 2 fronts. It uses the depreciated "show()" method and furthermore after it switches to the second card the buttons from card1 begin to mysteriously float through to the surface again!

```
public class test extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    final static int extraWindowWidth = 100;
    JButton jbtnOne = new JButton("Button 1");
        JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

        //Create the "cards".
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                size.width += extraWindowWidth;
                return size;
            }
        };


        card1.add(jbtnOne);
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));     
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));

        cardPanel.add(card1, "card1");
        cardPanel.add(card2, "card2");

        pane.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jbtnOne.addActionListener(this);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        test demo = new test();
        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource() ==  jbtnOne){
            System.out.println("HERE");
            card2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CardLayout` is managing the components so you will need to call `show` on the `CardLayout` instead of `JPanel#show`:

```
CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "card2");
```

Alternatively, when switching card components, you could also use

```
cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I didn't realise that it was the layout that you needed to call.